# pre_user_query meta_query admin user list

Tags: users, wp-user-query

I'm attempting to use `pre_user_query' to change the query to include some`meta_query` variables.

My goal is to only display users in the user list if they share a common `meta_value` with the current logged in user...

```
function modify_user_list($query){
    $user = wp_get_current_user();

    if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_user' ) ) return $query;

    $user_id = $user->ID; 
    $user_branch_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user_branch_number', true);

    $query->query_vars['meta_key'] = 'user_branch_number';
    $query->query_vars['meta_value'] = $user_branch_number; 
    $query->query_vars['meta_compare'] = '=';

}
add_action('pre_user_query', 'modify_user_list');
```

If I `print_r` the query it will show that the `query_vars` have been updated appropriately, but the user list in the admin panel is unaffected - same old list of every single user.

Comment: You aren't returning the $query after you change the vars.

Comment: @shanebp in this hook query has been passed by reference so there is no need to return the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `pre_user_query` according to WordPress documentation

> Fires after the WP_User_Query has been parsed, and before the query is
>   executed

Then you should use `pre_get_users` just like `pre_get_posts` when your arguments have some meaning to WordPress.

> `pre_get_users` Fires before the WP_User_Query has been parsed

Replace your hook with

`add_action('pre_get_users', 'modify_user_list');`

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize I was using the wrong hook !

Comment: any idea how to change the results above the list ? I still se e "100" subscribers, but only 5 are shown ( the five that should show )

Comment: @mkirkpatrick I din't get your question ? When I tested that snippet  it was working fine! Can you please brief  your problem a bit ?

Comment: The results int the list work as intended, but for some reason the sorting options above the list still include the total number of users.

Comment: Ah, Thanks for pointing this out! I got the new things in wp user query. Problem: Count is independent on current user query as wp using a function `count_users()` which is in `\wp-includes\user.php` and has its own separate query! Thus you search for users and no result found, count is still same. May you should post a new question for this.

Comment: I got a filter `views_users` but no luck as there is no global variable for current user query! so how can we alter the count ? And there is no filter in `count_users()` :(